# Ctrl+' (Apostrophe) Refactor! binding doesn't work when Notepad++ is open?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, notepad++, coderush, refactorpro

This is a really odd one that has been annoying me for some time, I use CodeRush and Refactor Pro at home and at work, since the switch to Visual Studio 2010 I have been unable to use the keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+') for the Refactor/CodeRush context menu:

[image]

For a long time I blamed VS2010 or CodeRush/Refactor! Pro for the issue and just worked round it with the mouse. At some point in time I realised that if Notepad++ was open the shortcut key didn't work.

Depending on what type of file is loaded in Notepad++ alters the effect; for example, if I have an XML/HTML/XAML file open a tag and all of it's children are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried Notepad++ v5.8.6 with some source files opened and IDETools 10.2.4 in Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7 and everything seems to work fine - the CTRL+' shortcut works as expected. Probably you might want to change the shortcut to something similar like CTRL+1 in the DevExpress\Options\IDE\Shortcuts options page.

Comment: If it was only happening on one computer I would put it down to weirdness, but two computers... one of them a fresh install. Have changed the shortcut which works around the problem. Thanks for trying it out.